# Regex for Source Medium Path in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So i'm trying to create a Regex find and replace function to take the Source Medium Path dimension from Google Analytics, and return a value that matches up with the Source Medium dimension.  For example, when I'm looking at the total conversions for Source Medium Path, I get values like:

1. google / cpc > google / organic
2. google / cpc > google / organic > (direct) / (none)
3. google / organic
4. (none) > (none) > (none) > google / organic > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)
5. (direct) / (none)

This isn't the prettiest format and will be difficult for our clients to understand in their reporting, so I'd like to replace these values with their equivalent Source / Medium dimension:

1. google / organic
2. google / organic
3. google / organic
4. google / organic
5. (direct) / (none)

The Regex find/replace function I've tried so far looks like it works for everything except the #4, where the Path ends with multiple iterations of 'direct / (none)', and mistakenly pulls in '(direct) / (none)' instead of 'google / organic'.

Essentially, this should find the last Source / Medium in the Path (ie 'google / organic' in 1 and 3), unless the last Group is '(direct) / (none)' (like in 2/4/5), in which case it should use the last Group that isn't '(direct) / (none)', and replace with the Source / Medium, unless the Path only contains one or more iterations of '(direct) / (none)', in which case it should replace with the value '(direct) / (none).

Any help in how I can fix this would be much appreciated!  See below for what I have so far:

find:  `^(.* \/ .* > )*(?'foo'.* \/ .*) > (direct \/ \(none\))+$|^(.* \/ .* > )(?'var'.* \/ .*)$`

replace with:  `${foo}${var}`

Comment: Try `^(?:(?:\(none\) > )+|(?:\w+ \/ \w+ > ))?(\w+ \/ \w+)(?!\S).*` and replace with group 1 See https://regex101.com/r/L6MnWN/1

Comment: Thank you!  that definitely fixed the issue I described.  However, I realized I forgot an important piece, being that if the Path only contains one or more iterations of '(direct) / (none)' then it should replace that value with just '(direct) / (none)'.  For example:

(direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)

and

(direct) / (none)

should both be replaced with '(direct) / (none)'.  I'm trying to figure out how to make that work with what you provided, but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Like this? `^(?:(?:\(none\) > )+|(?:\w+ \/ \w+ > ))?(\w+ \/ \w+|\(direct\) \/ \(none\))(?!\S).*` https://regex101.com/r/NQrhXr/1

Answer (score 2):

You might use a pattern to optionally match the preceding parts with none or word chars followed by a `/` and `>`

Then use a capturing group for either a `(none) > (none)` part or `word / word` part and use that in the replacement.

After group 1 you can match the rest of the string so that it will not be present in the replacement.

```
^(?:(?:\(none\) > )+|(?:\w+ \/ \w+ > ))?(\w+ \/ \w+|\(direct\) \/ \(none\))(?!\S).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hp84sQ/1)

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

Comment: Thanks again!  It looks like this works for all but one of the Paths:

google / organic > (direct) / (none) > (direct) / (none)

this should be replaced 'google / organic' but now it's replacing as '(direct) / (none)'.  Seems like it should be a simple enough fix but I haven't quite been able to crack it yet.

Comment: @aceetobee Like this? `^.*?(\S+ \/ \S+)(?!.*\w+ \/ \w).*` See https://regex101.com/r/plE18U/1